# Twitter strategy: Streaming API vs. REST API

Tags: twitter, streaming

I'm working on a kind of a twitter wall. Users can login with twitter and create their own wall, which will display the tweets for certain terms/hashtags.

I'm still looking for the best strategy to get the data out of the Twitter APIs.
Following some of my thoughts:

**Strategy 1: Streaming API**

- Open a single stream (POST statuses/filter) for all walls
- Each hashtag is added to the track parameter
- When new tweets arrive, they will be processed and sent to the corresponding wall
- ("one account, one application, one open connection" cf. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14935)

**Problems with the Streaming API**

- **Streaming api is limited to 400 keywords to track**
- What to do if there are more than 400 keywords to track?
- **Streaming api is limited to 1% of the tweets of the firehose**
- It's very difficult to get above 1% of the firehose, but if you're tracking a term like "apple" it'd be pretty easy to exceed the 1%. (cf. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6349)
- How can I handle such popular terms? Blacklist them?

**Strategy 2: REST Search API**

- Store user access tokens
- Poll the Search API (GET search/tweets) on behalf of the user, respecting the rate limits of 180 queries per 15 minute
- (cf. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11141)

**Problems with the REST Search API**

- **Polling**
- Could get very expensive to poll the API for a lot of users.

Do you have any suggestions/recommendations which strategy would fit the best? Are there already solutions for these problems?

Best regards